# A-frame: How to add clickable entity element?

Tags: three.js, aframe, webvr

This is what I am trying to achieve:

1. Load an image with marker (position on image)
2. Make the marker clickable
3. Upon clicking marker, change the image.

It is like a virtual tour where people can click on marker to enter the place.

Here is what I did so far:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        AFRAME.registerComponent('marker', {
            schema: {default: ''},
            init() {
                const sky = document.querySelector('a-sky');

                this.el.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    //sky.setAttribute('src', this.data);
                    console.log('clicked');
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <a-scene>
        <a-sky src="#entrance" rotation="0 -90 0" position="0 0 0" id="src-img-tpl"></a-sky>
        <a-sphere href="http://google.com" id="marker" position="-10 3 -15" radius="0.65" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
        <a-assets>
            <!-- <audio id="river" src="assets/Bg-music.wav" autoplay="true" loop="true"></audio> -->
            <img id="entrance" src="images/001.jpg">
            <img id="study" src="images/002.jpg">
            <img id="parking" src="images/003.jpg">
        </a-assets>

    </a-scene>

</body>
```

But it is not working for me. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to attach the component

```
<a-entity myComponentName> </a-entity>
```

Second of all, You're missing a cursor.
On a typical PC, its easy to test out your site using your mouse. Doing so requires adding the cursor component to the scene:

```
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">....
```

I've attached the cursor, and told it to use the mouse.
Check it out in [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2441xpv/2/). It's actually your code with the mentioned additions :)

---

Otherwise, You'd need to attach an entity, which will act as Your cursor.

The code is simple:

```
<a-entity camera>
  <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500"
        position="0 0 -1"
        geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03"
        material="color: black; shader: flat">
  </a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

It attaches a ring to the camera which allows you to click items by looking at them.

For a full description check out the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/cursor.html).

---

Worth mentioning, there is a full [tutorial on making a 360 gallery](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/guides/building-a-360-image-gallery.html) on the official website !